Run ribbon control when opening workbook
I am trying to open an excel file that has ribbon control that i need to run.
Sub Check_For_Completion(control As IRibbonControl)
end sub

I open the excel file but the control is not running. Here's the code to it:
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fileName:=MyFolder & "\" & MyFile)
Application.Run "'" & MyFile & "'!Check_For_Completion Nothing"


The subroutine Check_For_Completion requires a parameter to be passed. However, it seems that the control isn’t utilized in the subroutine’s code, so it would be more efficient to extract the code into a separate function that doesn’t require a parameter and can be called with ease

@Storax what if creating a separate function is not an option, is there no way to run that control ribbon?

Please elaborate

Application.Run "'" & MyFile & "'!Check_For_Completion", Nothing. The argument needs to be passed as an argument, not with the macro name.

@BigBen yes that did it. thank you.
